# BIOS interrupt _int86

Tags: c, interrupt, bios

I'm trying out some old code frome the book "Black art of 3d game programming". I know it is outdated but I started reading it and it's kind of fun and interesting. I downloaded the OpenWatcom C Compiler and made a new DOS Project in order to get this old code even compiled. I already compiled on piece of code where Videomode int13h is set and then I was able to draw pixels to the screen. But this was done with a C function called _setvideomode(). In the following example the videomode is set via the _int86 function which makes the interrupt call and the prototype should be in bios.h, but OpenWatcom says: No prototype found for function _int86. I am stuck now and don't know what to do ;) Here is the code:

```
void setGraphxMode(int mode){
    union REGS inregs,outregs;

    inregs.h.ah = 0;
    inregs.h.al = (unsigned char)mode;

    _int86(0x10,&inregs,&outregs);
}

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

Would appreciate any advise on this and yes I know: Graphics are done via DirectX or OpenGL these days. This is just for learning purpose! Thank you :)

Comment: Personally, I still write lots of graphics code in assembly directly.  When I teach assembly classes I actually start by teaching folks how to write a boot loader, get something running and then immediately start dealing with screen and memory management to get to protected mode.  It's really useful to figure out how to do things yourself so that you know better what it is you need from a graphics library.

Comment: Nice! I wish our professors would do that instead of boring Java... ;) now I have to dig into the material myself. Didn't even know that you can do that in protected mode (graphics I mean). I'd also like to do that what your describing you do in your class ;) Do you have any material on that? @DavidHoelzer

Comment: I've written a book that's just enough assembly to be dangerous.  I haven't quite released it yet.  As far as graphics in protected mode, the simplest way to approach the problem is to use a video mode for the card that will map the entire screen memory onto a flat memory region.  the SVGA extensions are a real mess and there's nothing standard, so trying to work through that manually will require an enormous amount of research into the documents for each specific card.  Much easier to just use a mapped memory mode and create a selector that points at it.

Comment: So it is possible to define a part of the RAM as screen memory and write data to it which will then be used by the videocard for drawing to the screen? would this even be possible under windows or linux then? @DavidHoelzer

Comment: More accurately, it's possible to select a screen mode that will map the display memory into RAM and to then define a selector so that you can access that region directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under OpenWatcom the call you are looking for is int386 I believe:

```
int386(0x10, &inregs, &outregs);
```

Comment: Yes! It works! Thanks :) My workaround to make the interrupt  via inline assembly: int 10h. That  did the job... But good to know :)